# How to extract hyperlink from Outlook mail to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to extract a hyperlink. There are several hyperlinks in the mail but this link is to download a file and it contains the word "download".

I receive several mails in the same mail format in a day. This is why I need to automate the downloading process.

As the first step, I extract the required link to Excel with below code in two modules

**Module 1**

```
Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Sub ExportAllHyperlinksInMultipleEmailsToExcel()
Dim objSelection As Selection
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim objMailDocument As Document
Dim objHyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim i As Long
Dim s As String

Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

If Not (objSelection Is Nothing) Then

   Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
   Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   objExcelApp.Visible = True
   objExcelWorkbook.Activate

   With objExcelWorksheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "No."
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Address"

  End With

  On Error Resume Next
  i = 0
  For Each objMail In objSelection
      objMail.Display
      Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
      If objMailDocument.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
         For Each objHyperlink In objMailDocument.Hyperlinks
              If InStr(10, objHyperlink.Address, "download") > 40 Then
                i = i + 1
                s = CStr(objHyperlink.Address)
                Call Module2.ExportToExcel(i, s, objExcelWorksheet)
             End If
         Next
      End If
      objMail.Close olDiscard
  Next
End If
End Sub
```

**Module 2**

```
  Sub ExportToExcel(n As Long, j As String, objExcelWorksheet AsExcel.Worksheet)

 Dim nLastRow As Integer

nLastRow = objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & objExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & nLastRow).Value = CStr(n)
objExcelWorksheet.Range("B" & nLastRow).Value = j

End Sub
```

The code runs but the generated Excel shows the values in Column A only (Mail No.). Column B, which should have the address of the hyperlink, remains blank.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? What value do you get after calling the `Hyperlink.Address` property?

Comment: Your `On Error Resume Next` statement may be hiding errors that would help you debug.

Comment: I tried by removing the statement On Error Resume Next and now it shows a "type mismatch" run time error in statement  "For Each objHyperlink In objMailDocument.Hyperlinks"  .. Anyone knows to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to call the `Display` method to get the mail item displayed in a separate window (inspector).

```
For Each objMail In objSelection
     ' objMail.Display
```

> which should have the address of the hyperlink remains blank.

```
         For Each objHyperlink In objMailDocument.Hyperlinks
              If InStr(10, objHyperlink.Address, "download") > 40 Then
                i = i + 1                
                Call Module2.ExportToExcel(i, objHyperlink.Address, objExcelWorksheet)
             End If
         Next
```

There is no need to cast the returned value to string. The [Hyperlink.Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlink.address) property returns the address (for example, a file name or URL) of the specified hyperlink as a string.

Comment: I tried deleting the objMail.Display but still the error is same :(.. When debugging the code , the Hyperlink.Address remains blank.. Hyperlink count returns the correct value but Hyperlink.Address returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to copy the link of the hyperlink using below function and now it is working ! thank you every one

```
objMailDocument.Hyperlinks(5).Address '5 is the number of the hyperlink which I need to extract the link from
```